# Many tooltips after upgrade to Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse

I've upgraded to Eclipse 3.5 and now tooltips are displayed for everything - for any field, for any method, for anything.
The worst thing is that they are displaying immediately after i've moved the mouse (no delay!) So almost always I do see some tooltip, this is very inconvenient.

How can I either increase the delay or disable tooltips?

Answer (score 2):

You can select what you want to enrich with tooltip during hover with the Preferences:

```
Java > Editor > Hover
```

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/9190/eclipsetexthover.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/9190/eclipsetexthover.png)

You can configure the delay with the Preferences:

```
General > Editors > Text Editors > "When mouse moved into hover"
```

[alt text http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/4841/eclipsejavahover.png](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/4841/eclipsejavahover.png)

Comment: i've deselected "combined hover" checkbox and this helped. no tooltips now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The hover text delay seems to come from a [registry setting](http://untamedmind.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/changing-the-mousehovertime-add-delay-on-the-tooltips-pop-up/), which can also be [changed with TweakUI](http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2008/09/tooltip-delay-in-windows.html).